# Firefox's password manager confuses site-wide login with any login fields inside the site

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, passwords

Let's say you have a site for saving your pets' credentials: you log in, then you can see your puppy's username/password and your kitten's username/password.

But in Firefox, if you choose to save your own logins just to get into the site, it will then auto-fill puppy's form and kitten's form with your credentials.

Chrome seems to behave correctly and Safari gives you the option (without automatically populating puppy/kitten's forms).

Is there something I can set on the forms so that browsers can differentiate them from the main site's login form?

Comment: FF's detection is pretty stupid. it checks for a few common field names, and/or the presence of an `<input type="password" ...>`, it also can't keep track of multi-stage logins, e.g. my CC co's page has a normal user/pass, then a second stage for the personal verification question, which is done as a password input. FF just fills in my password, and offers to update the main login with the verification question answer, which is obviously wrong.